# Jquery search througha class check if it has a certain id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hey I want to search through a class and check if that class contains a certain id. Do I have to use .each? if i do i dont know how to exactly use it, could someone show me how to use it in this context, 
any help is appreciated

```
  if(id == $('.people').attr('id'))
  {
       alert("person exists");
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since ids should not be used more than once, you simply can do:

```
if($('#' + id + '.people').length >= 1)
  alert('person exists');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can search for an ID with

```
$('#my-id')
```

In your case,

```
$('#' + id)
```

You can check if the result is empty by testing for `length`:

```
if($('#'+id).length == 0)
```

To verify that it is a `.person` element that has the given ID, you could test

```
if($('.person#'+id).length > 0) {
    alert('person exists');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an id can only be used once you can instead search for the element with that id and check if it has the class. That will be much faster:

```
$('#the-id').hasClass('the-class');
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a simple selector, and check if that element exists.

```
if ($('.people#'+id).length())  { //Checking length() checks if element exists
    alert("person exists");
}
```